# Getting data from several selected rows in a jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to get different values from a jTable, according to the selected rows (by the user).
I guess the code I already have should do that, but it always shows the same nr in all rows.
Can you guys get me some help ?

```
int linha  = Tabela.getSelectedRowCount();
Gerar ger = modelo.getGerar(linha);
System.out.println(linha);

for(int j = 0; j < linha; j ++) 
{
    int nr = ger.getNr();
    System.out.println(nr);

    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
    {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }

    String output = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(output);

    Gerar novo = new Gerar(nr, output);
    modelo.adicionaNovoGerar(novo);
}
```

**Update:**

```
public class Gerar implements Serializable 
{
    private Integer Nr;
    private String Passe;

    public Gerar(Integer Nr, String Passe) 
    {
        this.Nr = Nr;
        this.Passe = Passe;
    }

    public Integer getNr() 
    {
        return Nr;
    }

    public void setNr(Integer Nr) 
    {
        this.Nr = Nr;
    }
}
```

Comment: What `getNr();` will do? can you post that code

Comment: public class Gerar implements Serializable{
    private Integer Nr;
    private String Passe;

     public Gerar( Integer Nr, String Passe) {
        this.Nr = Nr;
        this.Passe = Passe;
    }
 
      
    public Integer getNr() {
        return Nr;
    }

    public void setNr(Integer Nr) {
        this.Nr = Nr;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I do it:

```
int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
if (selectedRows.length != 0) {
    for (int counter : selectedRows) {
        String value= table.getModel().getValueAt(counter, Constants.COLUMN).toString();
        /*
        * do stuff
        */
    }
}
```

And to give some context, I used this with a JTable that had info about the files in a folder. The app permitted me to delete files so, I used that piece of code to retrieve the name of the files selected and to delete them one by one.

In your case (i think) this line:

```
String value= table.getModel().getValueAt(counter, Constants.COLUMN).toString();
```

will turn into this:

```
Gerar ger = modelo.getGerar(counter);
```

**NB: I strongly recommend the use of a lower case letter as the first letter of an attribute( ex: private Integer Nr; -> private Integer nr;)**

Comment: As for the reasons your code doesn't work, @Madhan explains that in his answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 int linha  = Tabela.getSelectedRowCount();
```

This will give the no of selected Rows not the list of selected rows.

For which you have to go with [getSelectedRows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows())

```
Tabela.getSelectedRows();
```

which will returns the indices of all selected rows[return an integer array `int[]`]

And you are assigning the selectedRow count to class `ger`

```
 Gerar ger = modelo.getGerar(linha);
```

and inside the for loop you are calling

```
int nr = ger.getNr();
```

which will return the same value as many times you call, as the value is set before forloop